# Vectorize a 2-dimensional function in python

Tags: python, vectorization

I have a Python function, f, which takes a pair of numbers and return a calculation result on them, say, `x+y`

```
def f(x,y):
          return x+y
```

How can I  vectorize `f`, so for  given vectors X=(x1,...,xn) and Y=(y1,...,yn)

f_vectorized(X,Y) returns the array of f(x1,y1), f(x2,y2)...?

**EDIT**

Above, x+y is an example, but the actual calculation is more complex, so by regarding x and y as numpy vector does not necessarily work out-of-box.

Comment: Without seeing actual code, we can't tell you how to vectorize this thing properly. Using list comprehensions or `np.vectorize` will sacrifice all the performance benefits of NumPy, which is likely to be around a 1000x slowdown. Unless your code involves loops that fundamentally need to execute for a number of times that depends on the input, something like this should be fairly straightforward to vectorize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using `numpy` as input?

```
import numpy as np

def f(x,y):
     return x+y

a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [430]: f(a,b)
Out[430]: array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

**EDIT**

For more complex function you could use `list comprehension and` `zip`:

```
In [451]: [f(*par) for par in  zip(a, b)]
Out[451]: [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

**EDIT2**

Or you could use `np.vectorize` as you mentioned in the comment:

```
f_vec = np.vectorize(f)

In [470]: f_vec([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[470]: array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

**Perfomance**:

```
In [471]: %timeit f_vec([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop

In [472]: %timeit [f(*par) for par in  zip([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 µs per loop

In [476]: %timeit list(map(f, [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 µs per loop
```

So if you are interested in performance you should use `zip` and list comprehension or `map` solution suggested by @tglaria

Comment: Oh, sorry, I used x+y just as an example. The actual calculation in f is more complex so yours may not work in general. But you give some good points. Thanks.

Comment: I just realize there is another option: using numpy.vectorize as an annotation of the function.

Comment: Why are you using `list(map(...))` when `map(...)` already returns a list?

Comment: In python3 `map` return iterator and if you'd like to convert it to list you need to pass the result to `list` function

Comment: @AntonProtopopov would you look at that. I'm using Python 2.7 so I didn't know that difference in the map function (also, in 3 it stops iterating when the shortest iterable is exhausted).

Answer (score 2):

Well, isn't map supposed to be used for this?

```
def f(x,y):
    return (x,y, x+y)

print map(f,[0,1,2], [-1,0,-2])
>[(0, -1, -1), (1, 0, 1), (2, -2, 0)]
```